# "I will tell you in Latin, for French is of no use here"

Tags: mathematics, academic-latin, french

In a well-known [letter](http://mathix.org/linux/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/N0069975_PDF_204_209.pdf), Blaise Pascal, a French mathematician and philosopher, wrote (p. 7) 'je vous diray en Latin, car le Français n'y vaut rien' (I will tell you in Latin, for French is of no use here). To what extent was Latin a better language for writing mathematics than French in the 17th century?

This seems not to be a question of vocabulary since everything else in it is written in French.

Comment: Good question, especially since this immediately follows a paragraph where he makes essentially the same argument in French.

Comment: FWIW, when talking about computer science or computing in general, I tend to dislike using literal translations of concepts to my native Spanish (this is not universal to Spanish speakers, but does happen in other languages too, e.g. Italian). Maybe because in a technical context, English words have effectively become loanwords with far less ambiguous meanings. Think _mouse_ (non-existent in Spanish for any other meaning than the input device) vs _ratón_, _stack_ vs _pila_, etc. There is a subjective feeling that the foreign _scientific_ language is far more precise.

Comment: @Rafael And, funny enough, in English too those words feel technical in a way. Intuitively we *never* conflate the two senses of "mouse", for example. But French has taken the opposite route with *souris* and so forth, which makes it hard for me not to picture the rodent.

Comment: I don't think Latin was considered by Pascal a better language than French specifically for writing mathematics but that it was considered better for writing anything important and rigorous that could be shared with scholars all over Europe. Vernacular languages didn't have the prestige associated with Latin. They were evolving, less standardized while Latin, stricter and stable, was the language of knowledge.